# Table is missing a default value for the element (Spring boot + hibernate)

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying project on Spring boot, downloaded .zip from strat.spring.io and added my previous project.

I got 'Table is missing a default value for the element'.

My github
https://github.com/anatoliy19/spring_boot_test.git

The problem code is here:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String lastName, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id = " + id + "\n" +
                "Name = " + name + "\n" +
                "lastName = " + lastName + "\n" +
                "Age = " + age + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have these imports in your code `import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;` ? Shouldnt it be from `Javax.persistence.column`

Comment: It’s up to you  I will try

Comment: @Rishal  change to Javax.* helped me. Thanks!

Comment: He is using Spring Boot 3 which is using JPA 3 from JakartaEE so it should actually be `jakarta.persistence` and not `javax.persistence`. The problem is the `@Table` annotaion, he probably needs the `jakarta.persistence.Table` annotation instead of the Hibernate specific one. The same applies to the `@Id` that should be from `jakarta.persistence` as well and not from Spring Data.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for providing the information

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot 3.0.0.M4 which, as the version indicates, is a milestone version and not a final version for the upcoming Spring Boot 3. Spring Boot 3 uses JakartaEE 9 as a baseline and with that also a package change. So you are right in using the `jakarta.persistence` package for the annotations.

However the `@Table` you are using is coming from `org.hibernate.annotations` and you need the [`jakarta.persistence.Table`](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.0.0/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/Table.html) one instead.

The same, more or less, applies to the `@Id` currently you are using the Spring Data one and not the JPA one. You should import the [`jakarta.persistence.Id`](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.0.0/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/Id.html) one.

In your sample repo, not sure if you updated that or not, you need to remove the JPA 2.1 API dependency. Finally your entity should have the following imports:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
```

Answer (score -1):

For others adding the answer from comment to post.

Wrong imports of Table.

**If using Springboot version >= 3**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table; //correct import for Table
```

**If using Springboot version < 3**

It should be from the `javax.persistence.*`

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

**Update:** Thanks @[M.Denium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) for the correction related to JPA Upgrades.

For people using `Springboot version < 3` can use the imports which are mentioned above.
But for people using `Springboot version >= 3` it has been renamed to `Jakarta`.

Quote from Official Documentation: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

> The entire Spring team, and many in our community of contributors, are
> now preparing for the next generation of Spring. We are planning to
> release Spring Boot 3.0 in November 2022. This next major revision
> will be based on Spring Framework 6.0 and will require Java 17 or
> above. It will also be the first version of Spring Boot that makes use
> of Jakarta EE 9 APIs (jakarta.*) instead of EE 8 (javax.*).

https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6

Refer the blog for more details on the upgrade.

So, Use the imports as per your dependencies and check the correctness.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem and hides others (see my answer).

Comment: @M.Deinum I appreciate your answer but, it doesn't mean my answer is wrong or not solves the problem.